# Facebook - change thumbnail

Tags: html, facebook, image, facebook-like, thumbnails

I need to change the facebook like thumbnail image, I've tried this

```
<link rel="image_src" href="thisurl" />
```

and this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="thisurl"/>
```

I realized afterwards this needs to go in the head, but because of the structure of the code I'm not able to modify in there and still decide which url I need (i can't access the variables I have for the images in there), I can modify like this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...
modify in here
...
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried creating a meta tag with javascript in the area that I can change, that does not effect it

Does anybody know a way I can tell facebook which image I want as a thumbnail without having to modify inside of the head element

Answer (score 2):

The thumbnail image should go in the header just as you said, using rel="image_src" or the opengraph tag.

### Specify a thumbnail image in your html body

If Facebook can't get your thumbnail image from the header, it tries to get it from the content. It usualy takes the first image that it likes, so if you want to force a specific thumbnail not included in the page, put an invisible image (using the inline css *display:none*) just after the  tag:

```
<img src=”http://www.website.com/images/thumbnail.jpg” alt=”thumbnail” height=”200″ width=”250″ style=”display:none” />
```

Doing this, remember to:

- Avoid spaces in thumbnail name (FB doesn't manage spaces too well)
- Use a jpg (FB doesn't like png)
- Use the right dimensions (see below)

### Check your thumbnail's dimensions

Facebook doesn't like thumbnails of every size. The most important thing is the ratio between height and width that should be lesser than 1/3. So 40 & 100 would be ok, but 30 & 100 won't work. In addition, Facebook recently seems to prefer image with at least 200px in both dimensions (but don't forget the 1/3 rule).

### Clean Facebook Cache

Furthermore, you should clean the Facebook cache before every test using the Facebook Debug Tool (once knew as *Facebook Linter*):
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Insert your url in the form field and press Debug. You'll force Facebook to overwrite its information about your link. Sometimes you think there's still something wrong but it's just because it's using a wrong cached version of your page.

About Facebook Linter, be aware that (accordingly to he OGraph documentation):

> You can update the attributes of your page by updating your page's
>   tags. Note that og:title and og:type are only editable initially -
>   after your page receives 50 likes the title becomes fixed, and after
>   your page receives 10,000 likes the type becomes fixed. These
>   properties are fixed to avoid surprising users who have liked the page
>   already. Changing the title or type tags after these limits are
>   reached does nothing, your page retains the original title and type.